# Javascript: Submit a form via console

Tags: javascript, forms, console, submit

I want to submit a html form without pressing the button. The id of the form is "myForm" and this is the javascript code I am using:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

This actually works, but it is different than doing it on the normal way with pressing the button. There are some text fields and the values of the text fields should be saved. When I press the button the site reloads and the values of the text fields are saved. But if I change the values and then submit it via console, the site reloads, too, but the values are not saved.

Any explanations for it?

Comment: It should work... Add more context to your question...

Comment: Your code is OK when I try , please paste your form

Comment: Not the browser should save the values. On submit the values are posted to a php file and then they will be saved and if the site reloads the saved values get loaded. Thats why I have no Idea why it didnt work. It isnt my website btw, I try something just for fun.

Comment: Here is the form:

[http://pastebin.com/CSr231L8](http://pastebin.com/CSr231L8)

It is a betting game website and I try to automatic fill the text fields with values and then submit the form.